# how to upload file using dojo

Tags: dojo

How do I browse to upload a file using Dojo? See the code below:

```js
 dojox.io.xhrMultiPart({
              url: "http://localhost:8080/myWebService",
              handleAs: "xml",
              form: dojo.byId("myForm"), 
              load: function(data){ processRequest(data);},
              error: function(error){ processError(error); },
              backButton: function() { 
              },
              mimetype: "text/xml"         
        });
```

Now which code do I have to append to the above code to upload a file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use `dojox.form.Uploader` , which will enable you the "Browse" functionality.

```html
<input name="file" multiple="false" type="file" dojoType="dojox.form.Uploader" label="Select Class File" id="uploadedfile" />
```

I use `dojo.io.iframe.send` to upload file.
Then on the submit button of the form, I use following function to post,

```js
function addSwitchType(){
    var td = dojo.io.iframe.send({
        url: switchType_Add_URL,
        form: formName,
        method: "post",
        preventCache: true, 
        handleAs: "json",
        load: function(response, ioArgs){

            },
        error: function(response, ioArgs){

            }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use dojox.form.Uploader along with dojox.form.uploader.FileList.
Just declare these 2 as follows.

```js
up = new dojox.form.Uploader({
    label: "Select files",
    multiple: true,
    class: "browseButton",
    url: "UploadFile.php"
}).placeAt(form);

list = new dojox.form.uploader.FileList({
    uploader: up
}).placeAt(form);

btn = new Button({
    label: "upload",
    onClick: function() {
        up.upload();
    }
}).placeAt(form);

btn.startup();
up.startup();
list.startup();
```