# dojo 1.10 How to read text file a user has picked with a file picker

Tags: javascript, file-io, dojo

Using Dojo 1.10 (for consistency with existing GUI), I want the user to select a local JSON text file via a file picker, then read the file's contents into a JavaScript variable. Must work in IE9+. A RESTful server is available if required, but not mandatory.

I had some limited success with **dojox.form.Uploader**. The file picker and upload worked; the file contents could be read on the server, but there was no way to return the file contents back to the client. The browser also redirected to the form's URL which I don't want and *event.preventDefault()* on the form's *submit* didn't fix this.

Attempting to submit the HTML form containing the dojox.form.Uploader using **dojo.request.iframe** (as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11219973/how-to-upload-file-using-dojo)) resulted in a *415 Unsupported Media Type error*.

HTML's [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FileReader) looks most promising but isn't supported in IE9 and doesn't use Dojo.

There **has** to be a way to do this, can someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work. Just sharing the solution for the benefit of others. Technologies used:

- Jersey 2.x
- Jackson 2.4.x
- Jetty 9
- Java 8
- Dojo 1.10.x

Below is the HTML `<form>` containing the **dojox.form.Uploader**, allowing the user to pick a file to upload. Note that *uploadOnSelect* is set to false so we can upload manually via JavaScript:

```
<form id="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <input id="myUploader" type="file" name="theFile" data-dojo-type="dojox/form/Uploader" data-dojo-props="uploadOnSelect: false" />
</form>
```

Below is the JavaScript code that hooks into the "*change*" event of the Uploader, and uses a **dojo.request.iframe** to upload to a REST server via POST:

```
require([
    "dijit/registry", 
    "dojo/on", 
    "dojo/dom", 
    "dojo/request/iframe", 
    "dojo/json", ...], 
function(registry, on, dom, iframe, json){ 
    ...
    var me = this;
    on(registry.byId("myUploader"), "change", function() { me._getFileJSON.apply(me, arguments); });
    ...
    _getFileJSON : function() {
        var me = this;
        var td = iframe.post("rest/getFile", {
            form: dom.byId("uploadForm"),
            preventCache: true
        }).then(function(data) {
            ... use JSON returned
        }, function(error) {
            console.error(error);
        });
    }
    ...
});
```

Below is the server-side method that handles the POST, reads the given file and returns its JSON contents. Very important that the JSON to be returned is wrapped in the full `<html>` tag shown, including the `<textarea>` so that the **dojo.request.iframe** can read the response. Refer to [**dojox.form.Uploader**](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/form/Uploader.html) documentation.

*MyPersistenceObj* is a simple POJO that matches the JSON structure in the received file. The transformation from JSON to POJO and back to JSON isn't strictly necessary, but provides the ability for additional processing using the POJO (not included for brevity).

```
@POST
@Path("/getFile")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public String uploadFile(
    @FormDataParam("theFile") InputStream inData,
    @FormDataParam("theFile") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) {

    try {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        MyPersistenceObj data = mapper.readValue(inData, MyPersistenceObj.class);

        ObjectWriter ow = mapper.writer();
        String dataAsJson = ow.writeValueAsString(data);
        return "<html><head></head><body><textarea>" + dataAsJson + "</textarea></body></html>";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return "<html><head></head><body><textarea>{ \"error\" : \"invalid JSON: "
            + (e.getMessage() != null ? e.getMessage().replaceAll("[\"'\\r\\n]", "") : "<N/A>")
            + "\" }</textarea></body></html>";
    }
}
```

I again acknowledge [how to upload file using dojo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11219973/how-to-upload-file-using-dojo), which presents a partial solution to this.